Can I add the controller part of the MVC pattern to the MTV pattern in Django?
I'm trying to develop a multiplayer web game using Django. I understand that in Django's MTV Pattern, the view part takes on the role of the controller. But the view part needs a user in the frontend who accesses the website in order to be able to carry out actions. But in my WebGame there are also actions that need to be executed in the background, which need to be executed at certain times without any user in the frontend. So can I insert a folder in my Django code with the controller classes and specify when which function should be executed regularly?
If I'm on the wrong path when it comes to solving my problem, I'm of course also interested in alternative suggestions.
I watched a few videos and read a few books, but I couldn't find anything that really matched my problem.
